# How to insert a movie on button click - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, action

I'v been working on a strobe website for a while now http://strobepage.com/

I want to allow users to select their own colours for the strobe, This Basically means I will easily be able to cover way more colour combinations and take up less room on the site..
So far I have tried making 2 movie clips, one for each colour..  and refering to it as an instance and as a movie clip as a whole (  MovieClip(colour1)  ) to change its colour.. this works, but only in that specific instance, when the user clicks "next" to progress to the next frame of the ROOT movie (which displays the interchanging movie clips) the movie clips have reverted back to their original state..

Is there possibly a way to PERMANENTLY colour a movie clip on button press...  I seem to think there isnt..  This is where i thought, hey, why not make a bunch of movie clips that contain different colours, and on button press, one of these movie clips, is inserted into another movie clip that will have 2 frames that interchange between the movie clips that the user has selected... Only, I have no idea how to do this, and whether its possible or not..

I hope i have explained this in an understandable way..  theres lots of movieclips lol..

anyway, thanks in advance for anyone who can come up with a solution :D

Please give an AS3 example of what you are explaining :D

Comment: There are lots of ways to permanently color your movie clip.  Are you looking for quickest way to do it with timeline code, or the most efficient way?  Do you already have the buttons setup?

Answer (score 0):

Create movie clip for each color and place on the same x, y.
Now keep them all visible=false and make particular mc to visible=true. Use colortranform to reflect the changes on other mc's.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it light and easy to maintain, you'll want to use code, not timeline frames to get your colors (this will also ensure faster performing strobes).  This is quite easy to accomplish with [ColorTransform](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html). Below is a function I've written that encapsulates that operation; accepting the object you want to color as the first argument, and a hexidecimal value of the color as the second.

```
function tint(obj:Object, color:uint):void {
    /* Colors the object using transform */

    // Pull the individual primaries
    var r:Number = (color >> 16 ) & 0xFF;
    var g:Number = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
    var b:Number = color & 0xFF;

    // Apply if valid
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty("transform")) {
        obj.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(0,0,0,1,r,g,b,0);
    }
}
```

In example, let's assume you have a DisplayObject on stage called "box", and wanted to color it a bright blue, you'd do the following:

```
tint(box, 0x1b8afc);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You could just do:  `var ct:ColorTransform = mc.transform.colorTransform;   ct.color = 0xFF0000;  mc.transform.colorTransform = ct;`